# Redirecting gfortran errors and warnings DURING COMPILATION to a text file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I want to redirect gfortran errors and waring during compilation to a text file by using redirection >.
`gfortran -Wall -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -fd-lines-as-comments -nocpp FCAC0000.FOR > error.txt`. I am not able to do this in anyway.
I am using gfortran 4.10 on windows (mingw win32 binary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`> output.txt` (short for `1> output.txt`) redirect stdout to file

`2> error.txt` redirect stderr to file

This works on both Linux and Windows. Here's some [reading](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930) on redirecting stream on Windows.

Comment: Though I had read such things many places but could never understood the way it is to be used. Thanks for directing to very lucid resource which cleared my understanding. Regards.